# How could I set a boolean value to True, and make it so if a condition is met, it becomes False, but only for a certain amount of time?

Tags: python, boolean

Seems like there should be a simple solution using the `time` module or something, but I've tried a few things and nothing seems to work. I need something like this to work:

```
hungry = True
if line.find ('feeds'):
    #hungry = False for 60 seconds, then hungry is true again
```

Anyone have a solution for this?

edit: As for what I've tried, I've tried this bit of code:

```
if hungry==True:
     print('yum! not hungry for 20 seconds')
     hungry = False
     i = 20
     while(i>0):
         i-=1
         time.sleep(1)
         if(i==0):
             hungry = True
```

But that doesn't work because the program  just pauses until `hungry` is True again, and `hungry` being false while the program sleeps won't help; it should be false for a certain amount of time while the rest of the program works

edit: It looks like this won't be possible without threading. I'll have to either find a new solution, or learn to use threading. Thanks for all the help anyways, I seriously appreciate it!

Comment: On a second reading, I'm no longer sure that I've understood your question. Is there another thread in your program that you want to run while `hungry` is false? Why are you sleeping for 1 second 20 times instead of just sleeping for 20 seconds?

Comment: @Emily I think he wants to run two threads: 1) The main program 2) After `hungry = False`, set `hungry` to True after 60 seconds.

Comment: @Arnav: threading isn't necessary at all.  I didn't use it, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could encapsulate the behaviour you want in a `TimedValue` class, but that might be overkill here-- I'd probably just do something like

```
now = time.time()
hunger = lambda: time.time() > now + 60
```

and then use `hunger()` whenever I wanted the value instead of `hungry`.  That way, the code doesn't block, and we can continue doing work, but `hunger()` will give us the right state.  E.g.

```
import time
now = time.time()
hunger = lambda: time.time() > now + 60
for i in range(10):
    print 'doing stuff here on loop', i
    time.sleep(10)
    print 'hunger is', hunger()
```

produces

```
doing stuff here on loop 0
hunger is False
doing stuff here on loop 1
hunger is False
doing stuff here on loop 2
hunger is False
doing stuff here on loop 3
hunger is False
doing stuff here on loop 4
hunger is False
doing stuff here on loop 5
hunger is True
doing stuff here on loop 6
hunger is True
doing stuff here on loop 7
hunger is True
doing stuff here on loop 8
hunger is True
doing stuff here on loop 9
hunger is True
```

Comment: Why the sleep() call? If it's there to guarantee that we see `hunger is True`, then is there a reason you didn't instead loop on `while hunger() = False`? There are no guarantees on how long `sleep` actually causes the thread to sleep for, so sleeping for 10 seconds in a loop that runs 10 times doesn't guarantee that we will get to `hunger is True`.

Comment: @Emily: the sleep call was there just to kill time.  I wanted only several print statements, and if I did `while not hunger():` then I'd get a lot of them unless I was more clever than it was worth being.  What matters is the behaviour of `hunger()`.

Comment: Took me a bit of work to incorporate it into the rest of the code, but in the end, the whole hunger() idea was what helped the most! Thank you SO much.

Comment: @Arnav: glad I could help.  This is the simplest approach I could think of, but using `threading.Timer` and a callback function, as done in @the wolf's answer, is a rich approach, and worth learning.

Comment: There is also a very nice [`Timer` example over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45728837/2192488).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of accuracy you're requiring, but maybe you can just sleep for 60 seconds and then set the variable to true?

```
from time import sleep
hungry = True
if line.find('feeds'):
  hungry = False
  sleep(60)
  hungry = True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something along these lines:

```
from threading import Timer
import time

class Time_out(object):
    def __init__(self,secs):
        self.timer = Timer(secs,self.set_false)
        self.hungry=True
        self.timer.start()

    def set_false(self):
        self.hungry=False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=Time_out(1)
    y=0
    t1=time.time()
    while x.hungry:
        y+=1
        # this loop -- do whatever... I just increment y as a test...

    print 'looped for {:.5} seconds, y increased {:,} times in that time'.format(time.time()-t1, y)
```

Prints:

```
looped for 1.0012 seconds, y increased 5,239,754 times in that time
```

The value I used here for the timeout is 1 second but you can use your own value. Then do the work in the `while` loop. This is a very primitive but effective callback.

The advantage is you can have many `Time_out` objects and the loop will keep going until nobody is hungry!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use something like the code below. This is an elegant OOP solution which is convenient to use and maintain.

```
from time import time

class TimedProperty(object):

    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        self.value1 = value1
        self.value2 = value2
        self.start_time = -1
        self.time_value = 0

    @property
    def value(self):
        if self.valuenum == 0:
            return self.value1
        else:
            return self.value2

    @property
    def valuenum(self):
        if time() - self.start_time > self.time_value:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

    def switch_for(self, seconds, value=None):
        self.start_time = time()
        self.time_value = seconds
        if value is not None:
            self.value2 = value
```

Usage:

```
def main():
    p = TimedProperty(True, False)
    print p.value
    print p.valuenum
    p.switch_for(0.2)
    print p.value
    print p.valuenum
    sleep(0.5)
    print p.value
    print p.valuenum
```

Output:

```
True
0
False
1
True
0
```

Example on codepad.org: http://codepad.org/glujHgey *(sleep() is forbidden on codepad, its been replaced by a time consing  for loop)*

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution:

```
from time import time # time() is the time in seconds since the epoch (January 1st, 1970)
hungry = True
if line.find('feeds'):
    start, hungry = time(), False # it will be a fraction of a second off 
    while 1:                      # because hungry is set to False right 
        if (time() - start) >= 60:  # after start is set to the current time
            hungry = True             
            break
```

NOTE: This may not be exactly 60 seconds because `time()` (at least, I am told this) can be affected by the memory usage of the program; thus, it may be slightly off.

Also, unless you use threading, you can't really do anything else in the program.
You could run the rest of the program in the `while` loop, though.

EDIT: You could create a function that does this. Thus, you can have part of the program run, then check if it is time to change the value of hungry again:

```
def isHungry(start):
     from time import time
     if (time() - start) >= 60: hungry = True # if 60 seconds has passed
     else: hungry = False
     return hungry

from time import time
# some code
if line.find('feeds'):
    start = time()
# a bit of code
hungry = isHungry(start)
# more code
hungry = isHungry(start)
```